Headless - Can child items have its own style parameters?
I have a rendering with a data source item, and under it are child items; both of which are being retrieved via GraphQL. One of our requirements is for these child items to be styled differently and these Styling Parameters must be configurable in Pages Editor, however, the styling parameters are only for the root of the component.
I discovered in the ColumnSplitter that each column has its own Styling Parameters. Is it similarly possible for each of the data source’s child items to have its own separate styling parameters?
EDIT: Added an info that the styling parameters for child items must be available in Pages Editor

If you want the component to support grids and styles, variants, and dynamic placeholders.Inherit all of the following base templates to the rendering parameters template: BaseRenderingParameters, IDynamicPlaceholder, _PerSiteStandardValues, and IRenderingId.

I already have that for the main rendering. I’m just curious if it is possible to have a styling parameter for the child items, and possibly be able to configure it in Pages Editor
